# Why does git on Windows fail to recognise remote branches

Tags: git

I use git on Linux all the time without any issue. However I recently had to use git on Windows so I installed the command line client because that's how I work most happily.

My problem is that I tried to checkout a branch that I'd created on Linux using `git checkout mybranchname` but it didn't work. I had to specify `git checkout -b mybranchname --track origin/mybranchname`.

Since then, whenever I go to push I get told

```
fatal: The upstream branch of your current branch does not match
the name of your current branch.  To push to the upstream branch
on the remote, use

    git push origin HEAD:mybranchname

To push to the branch of the same name on the remote, use

    git push origin mybranchname

To choose either option permanently, see push.default in 'git help config'.
```

Does anyone know why this happened or how to resolve it?

I'm using git version 2.12.0.windows.1 and 2.11.0 on Linux. My origin is GitHub Enterprise over SSH in both cases.

Comment: Have you made sure you've spelled the branches correctly? I ask because you said that checking out an existing branch "didn't work". The problem is, **it should**. If you had fetched from the remote, and `git branch -a` lists the branch as `origin/mybranchname` then `git checkout mybranchname` should create a local branch and track the remote branch, automatically. Since all you say is that "it didn't work", it's hard to guess at what the problem is.

Comment: I had copied and pasted it so was sure I had everything correct - except I had an invisible control character in there too some how. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

In the first command, you are checking out out a local branch that must already exist. In the second command, you are creating a new local branch and associating with a remote branch.

The scenarios are different.

If the local branch didn't exist before, I would run:

```
git branch mybranchname origin/mybranchname -u
```

The -u option sets up the remote branch to be upstream of the local branch, so  you can do:

```
git push
git pull
```

Without having to qualify the remote:

```
git push origin mybranchname
git pull origin mybranchname
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that git for Windows had somehow added a unicode character to the branch name that cannot be displayed in the command prompt.

One of my branches was called `mybranchname` but for some unknown reason the remote branch was called `\u0096mybranchname` (I had not asked for that!)

Solution: Delete Windows and never again make the mistake of using that dreadful OS with it's awful small file IO and random ignoring of characters in command windows.